# how to check whether a user is logged in in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I know about request.user.is_authenticated() but i created a custom user(model) and created login page for it
now how can we know if the user is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

In views.py once the user logs in redirect to a url that calls a view

```
@login_required()
def login_success(request):
```

and render a welcome message